# Help with formula to concatenate fields, if both fields are not null

Tags: community, formula

Please help with the formula below. I'm trying to concatenate two fields if they're Null.  Thanks

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Service__c,"") || ISNULL(BusinessID__c),
    NuLL,Service__c && BusinessID__c)
```

Comment: Why would you ever add null to null? That does not seem useful.

Comment: The reason is, I only want to concatenate the fields if both fields are not NULL otherwise leave it blank. Users often time create accounts without knowing these fields.  They often create duplicate account with the same id.  I'm trying to prevent that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator for concatenation

You have:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Service__c,"") || ISNULL(BusinessID__c), NuLL,Service__c && BusinessID__c)
```

This is "anding" Service__c and BusinessId__c

You want:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Service__c,"") || ISNULL(BusinessID__c), NuLL,TEXT(Service__c) & BusinessID__c)
```

assuming both fields are strings

Comment: I get the following error: Error: Field Service__c may not be used in this type of formula

Comment: ah, should have seen that, `service__c` is a picklist so it must be wrapped by TEXT(..). Updated answer. If BusinessId__c is also a picklist, do the same for it

Comment: Also, use ISBLANK, not ISNULL. ISNULL is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Below are couple of examples:

1.For two number field:

```
VALUE(TEXT(NumberField1__c) & TEXT(NumberField2__c))
```

2.Formula field type text:

```
Full Name = LastName & ", " & FirstName (for lookup field type it Concatenates IDs )
```